# Error on Python DB Connection PostgreSQL (Module)

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

Currently, I am learning about databases with `Python`.

I am trying to make `postgresql` database connection under the OOP paradigm.
I followed all the steps from this [article](https://towardsdatascience.com/connect-to-postgresql-database-server-using-psycopg2-with-an-elegant-configuration-file-dba6fc885989), but I got an error when I run my code.

All the code is the same, I just modified the `database.ini` file with my DB setting.

** `database.ini` code:

```
[postgresql]
host = localhost
port = 5432
database = dvdrental
user = postgres
password = 1234
```

** `config.py` code:

```
# import libraries
from configparser import ConfigParser
import configparser
from pathlib import Path

def get_project_root() -> Path:
    ''' Return project root folder '''
    return Path(__file__).parents[1]

def config(config_db):
    
    section = 'postgresql'
    
    config_file_path = 'config/' + config_db

    if (len(config_file_path) > 0 and len(section) > 0):
        # create an instance of ConfigParser class
        config_parser = ConfigParser()

        # read the configuration file
        config_parser.read(config_file_path)

        # if the configuration file contains the provided section name
        if(config_parser.has_section(section=section)):
            # read options of the sections
            config_params = config_parser.items(section=section)

            # convert the list object to a python dictionary object
            # define an empty dict
            db_conn_dict = {}

            # loop in the list
            for config_param in config_params:
                # get options key and value
                key = config_params[0]
                value = config_params[1]

                # add the key value pair in the dictionary object
                db_conn_dict[key] = value
            
            # get connection object use above dictionary object
            return db_conn_dict
```

** `db_conn.py` code:

```
# import libraries
import pandas as pd 
import psycopg2
from config.config import config

# take in a PostgreSQL table and outputs a pandas dataframe
def load_db_table(config_db, query):
    params = config(config_db)
    engine = psycopg2.connect(**params)
    data = pd.read_sql(query, con = engine)
    return data
```

** `main.py` code:

```
# import library
from src.data.db_conn import load_db_table
from config.config import get_project_root

# project root
PROJECT_ROOT = get_project_root()

# read database
df = load_db_table(config_db = 'database.ini', query = 'SELECT * FROM actor LIMIT 5')

print(df)
```

The **problem** is, when I run the program I got the `error`:

```
TypeError: connect() keywords must be strings
PS D:\ASUS\MY CODES PYTHON\Iochordxsyy\db_connection> python main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = load_db_table(config_db = 'database.ini', query = 'SELECT * FROM actor LIMIT 5')
  File "D:\ASUS\MY CODES PYTHON\Iochordxsyy\db_connection\src\data\db_conn.py", line 9, in load_db_table
    engine = psycopg2.connect(**params)
TypeError: connect() keywords must be strings
```

This is the message when I `debugged` my code:

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError
connect() argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType
  File "D:\ASUS\MY CODES PYTHON\Iochordxsyy\db_connection\src\data\db_conn.py", line 9, in load_db_table
    engine = psycopg2.connect(**params)
  File "D:\ASUS\MY CODES PYTHON\Iochordxsyy\db_connection\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    df = load_db_table(config_db = 'database.ini', query = 'SELECT * FROM actor LIMIT 5')
```

I have checked all the code is the same as the article but I have no ideas why the error still occurs. Do you have any ideas?

If you have any ideas/solutions, it will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Credit:
Thank you for the authors of the articles mentioned above.

Comment: If you print `params`, what do you get?  [edit] the question to show the output.

Comment: Hi, @snakecharmerb thank you for the comment. I already got where the error comes from. There is a mistake on the ```config.ini``` --> "config_params[]". It is supposed to be "config_param[]". Thank you for the comments. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think "**username**" keyword in **database.ini** must be "**user**".

** database.ini code:

```
[postgresql]
host = localhost
port = 5432
database = dvdrental
user = postgres
password = 1234
```

Comment: Hi @Muhammed YILMAZ thank you for your comment.
I have modified from username to user, but the error still occurs.

But, thanks for the correction of my mistake.

Comment: Is the config.py and database.ini files in the config/ directory?

Comment: Yes, those two files (config.py and database.ini) are in the config/ directory.

Comment: The documentation (https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html)  shows how to use the connect function. Instead of getting the database information from the database.ini file, you can try entering manuel. If the connection is established without any problems, you can print the return value of the config.config() function, that is params variable, and check if it is different from the values you have given manually.

Comment: "database" is used for the database name in the database.ini file. I think it should be "dbname" too but I am not sure

Comment: Hi, I know where I got the error. There is a mistake in ```config.py``` file. The code should be like this:
```
....
key = config_param[0]
value = config_param[1]
...
```

Anyway, thank you very much for your help. I learn something from our discussion.

Answer (score 0):

**[Solved]**

Hi all, I got the answer. There is a mistake script on the `config.ini` file.
`I change the script from "config_params[]" to "config_param[]"`

** the **correct** script:

```
...
key = config_param[0]
value = config_param[1]
...
```

Thank you for all the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Align the indentation of this: config.py, as shown below.

```
if (len(config_file_path) > 0 and len(section) > 0):
    # create an instance of ConfigParser class
    config_parser = ConfigParser()

    # read the configuration file
    config_parser.read(config_file_path)

    # if the configuration file contains the provided section name
    if(config_parser.has_section(section=section)):
        # read options of the sections
        config_params = config_parser.items(section=section)

        # convert the list object to a python dictionary object
        # define an empty dict
        db_conn_dict = {}

        # loop in the list
        for config_param in config_params:
            # get options key and value
            key = config_params[0]
            value = config_params[1]

            # add the key value pair in the dictionary object
            db_conn_dict[key] = value
        
        # get connection object use above dictionary object
return db_conn_dict
```